# asp.net mvc meta description character issue

Tags: character-encoding, meta

I designed the layout view page like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
   1 <META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=windows-1254>
   2 <META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=utf-8>
   3 <META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=iso-8859-9>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.Description"/>
```

and when run the application and view the borwser source, some caharecters are appeared invalid as following.

```
<meta name="description" content="s&#252;r&#252;"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `@HTML.Raw(...)` like this:

```
<title>@Html.Raw(ViewData["Title"])</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 different charset META-tags which makes absolutely no sense.

Otherwise META "description" looks fine - contains properly encoded value of "sü;rü" string.

Comment: Does it make any difference from a SEO point of view that the text is encoded? And also, are the charset, content and http-equiv meta fields important?

Comment: @Jeroen, consider asking first question as question - no idea. For the second - depends if you serve correct headers or not... - HTML should match resulting encoding.